# What's the best way to store non-overlapping date ranges in (My)SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm building a system managing students and classes. Students can change classes, but they can't be assigned to more than one class on a given day. I'm having second thoughts regarding the way I implemented it.

The obvious way would have been to have an `attendance_periods` table, with the columns  `student_id`, `class_id`, `from` and `to`. However, that would make it possible for invalid data to be stored. For example, having Student A in Class A from 2021-08-01 to 2021-09-01 and on Class B from 2021-08-15 to 2021-09-15. At least, as far as I know, there's no way to prevent such cases at the database level.

To prevent this kind of overlap from happening, I made the table only have `student_id`, `class_id` and `from`, with the pair `student_id` and `from` being unique and `class_id` nullable. Instead of a row "saying" a student is in class X from date A to date B, the row only says when the student joined a class or left the school (if they're not assigned to any classes).

However, this has been making some queries very difficult. For example, to get what students are on which class on a given day, this is the query I've been using:

```
select
  `class_attendance_periods`.*
from
  `class_attendance_periods`
  left join (
    select
      `id` as `later_id`,
      `student_id` as `later_student_id`,
      `class_id` as `later_class_id`,
      `from` as `later_from`
    from
      `class_attendance_periods`
    where
      `from` <= '2021-08-30'
  ) as `later` on `class_attendance_periods`.`student_id` = `later`.`later_student_id`
  and `class_attendance_periods`.`from` < `later`.`later_from`
where
  `later`.`later_from` is null
  and `class_attendance_periods`.`from` <= '2021-08-30'
```

However, what I'm working on now requires fetching each class' students for a period of time. It's certainly something I could make work on the PHP side of the server, but I don't know how to limit the query to the rows that apply. For example, a `WHERE from <= last_day_of_the_interval` condition prevents fetching future attendance periods that I don't need, but I don't know how not to fetch past rows that are not required. Also, I'd like to have the DB do the heavy lifting if possible.

So my question is twofold:

1- Is there a better way to implement this kind of case? I'm interested in having the DB not allow invalid data, while making it easy to query a class' students on a given day or all classes' students on a given period of time.

2- If this structure isn't too bad, is there a way to make the query calculate the end of the attendance period (i.e., the "to" date) dynamically? Something like adding a `next attendance period's 'from' minus one day` column. That way queries would be much easier to make.

Comment: I would use a trigger `BEFORE` `UPDATE`/`INSERT` that will check the datas and either perform the update or send an ERROR signal. I actually don't have enough time to write a proper answer, but you may have everything needed to do some researches

Comment: *However, this has been making some queries very difficult.* Maybe your MySQL version is too ancient, and it needs in upgrade?

Comment: @Cid I have never used triggers before (as you can probably tell from the question, I'm hardly experienced in SQL) but I might look into it, if no better alternative comes up. Thank you for the hint!

Comment: @Akina I don't mean solely in terms of performance. For example, if the table I'm using had a `to` column, instead of the query above a `SELECT * FROM attendance_periods WHERE from <= $date AND to >= $date` would suffice. So the current query is easier to mess up, harder to debug, and, yes, slower. I guess I'm looking for a way to keep things simple.

Comment: @sakinobashi this could be a good use case to learn about them

Comment: I'm not sure your schema is really preventing overlap anyway, only the start date. And why can't a student be in two classes on the same day?

Comment: @GarrGodfrey Students have one "main" class, which this table is meant to track. And if the pair `student_id` and `from` has to be unique, it should literally be impossible for the same student to be in multiple classes on the same day, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @sakinobashi perhaps I'm confused by the example you gave. 2021-08-01 and 2021-08-15 are the "from" dates, right? So a student could be enrolled in both?

Comment: @GarrGodfrey that's an example of how relying on a `to` column would allow for such invalid (for my use case) data. If there's no `to` column, then the students' class is determined solely by the `from` column; they would be in class A from 08-01, and on class B from 08-15. In other words, current class = row with the most recent `from` date.

Comment: I think I see, you want to deduce the class end date from the start date of the subsequent class.

Answer (score 2):

> However, this has been making some queries very difficult. For example, to get what students are on which class on a given day

```sql
WITH
cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY student_id ORDER BY `from` DESC) rn
    FROM class_attendance_periods
    WHERE `from` <= '2021-08-30'
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Needs MySQL version 8+.

Comment: I've never used `ROW_NUMBER()` nor `PARTITION BY` before, but since I'm already using MySQL 8 I'll look into it

Answer (score 0):

Working from Akina's answer as a starting point, I ended up with the following query:

```
WITH
cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY student_id ORDER BY `from` ASC) rn
    FROM class_attendance_periods
)
SELECT cte.*, DATE_SUB(`cte2`.`from`, INTERVAL 1 DAY) as `to`
FROM cte
LEFT JOIN cte AS cte2 ON (cte.student_id = cte2.student_id AND cte.rn + 1 = cte2.rn)
WHERE `cte`.`from` <= $end_date
HAVING (`to` >= $start_date OR `to` IS NULL);
```

This query adds a `to` column, calculated dynamically from the original table, without too much of a performance hit: the query on the question body takes about 3ms and only works for a single day, this query takes about 5ms and can be used for date intervals.

I still need to run tests and make sure the data is indeed valid and there aren't any unexpected downsides to this approach, but for the time being this seems to meet solve my issue.